# Blocking SIGQUIT when SIGUSR1 handler is running

Tags: c, signals, fork, sigaction

I have the following program which I have almost solved:

> There are two processes: a parent process (P0) creates five children; after that, the parent process sends five times a SIGUSR1 signal to each of its children and goes sleeping for 1 second. Then, the parent process sends a SIGQUIT signal to each child and waits for all of them to terminate.
>
> Each child process:
>
> 1. waits for a signal: if a SIGQUIT signal arrives, the child process exits; if a SIGUSR signal arrives, then the child prints the text "Even, PID = ..." if it has an even PID, "Odd, PID = ..." otherwise.
>    The child process must not terminate before it has received the SIGQUIT signal from the parent.
>
> Make sure that the execution of the SIGUSR1 signal handler can't be stopped by the incoming of a SIGQUIT signal.

Now, this is what I've got so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define NUM_CHILDREN 5
#define NUM_ITER  5

void sigusr1_handler(int sig);

int main(void) {

 int i;
 pid_t children[NUM_CHILDREN];
 
 struct sigaction act;
 struct sigaction act2;
 act.sa_handler = sigusr1_handler;
 act.sa_flags = 0;
 sigaddset(&act.sa_mask,SIGQUIT);
 sigaction(SIGUSR1,&act,0);
 sigaction(SIGQUIT,&act,0);
 
 for(i = 0; i < NUM_CHILDREN; i++) {
  figli[i] = fork();
  switch(figli[i]) {
   case -1:
    fprintf(stderr,"Error with fork()!");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   case 0:
    while(1) pause();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   default:
    break;
  }
 }
 
 for(i = 0; i < NUM_ITER; i++) {
  for(i = 0; i < NUM_CHILDREN; i++) {
   kill(children[i],SIGUSR1); 
   sleep(1);
  }
 }
 
 for(i = 0; i < NUM_CHILDREN; i++) {
  kill(children[i],SIGQUIT);
 }
 
 for(i = 0; i < NUM_CHILDREN; i++) {
  wait(NULL);
 }
 
 exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void sigusr1_handler(int sig) {
 if(sig == SIGUSR1) {
  if((getpid() % 2)==0)
   printf("Even, PID = %d\n",getpid());
  else printf("Odd, PID = %d\n",getpid());
 }
 if(sig == SIGQUIT) exit(0);
}
```

I've already looked up how to block signals when handling other ones and I can't use sigprocmask() (as this is a course exercise and we didn't use that function).
I don't understand if my solution is working properly, if I try to send a SIGQUIT signal when each child is handling the SIGUSR1 signal (for example by sending it from terminal with CTRL-\ ) I get two scenarios:

1. without the `if(sig == SIGQUIT) exit(0)` line in the `sigusr1_handler` function, the program doesn't stop and I get this output:

> Even, PID = 5296
>
> ^\Odd, PID = 5297
>
> Even, PID = 5298
>
> Odd, PID = 5299
>
> Even, PID = 5300

but then the program gets stuck because none of the children is handling the SIGQUIT signal the parent is sending; if I put the `if(sig == SIGQUIT) exit(0)` line in the handler, then pressing CTRL - \ makes the program stop, making both parent and children exit. I'm not sure but I thought this could happen because when I send the SIGQUIT signal with CTRL - \ and the program is running, I'm not actually sending the signal to the children but to the parent process (?), therefore with another terminal I've tried to send a SIGQUIT signal with `kill(pid,signal)` to one of the children running in that moment, but this doesn't seem to work properly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't safely call `printf()` or `exit()` from within a signal handler.  In general, [you can't make any function calls from within a signal handler](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note188).  POSIX extends that and [allows for the calling of async-signal-safe functions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03) but neither `printf()` nor `exit()` are async-signal-safe.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that but I don't know if this would solve my problem... You think that with async-signal-safe calls the code would be correct?